# Alterar senha do usuario(Active Directory) usando php e powershell

Tags: php, powershell, active-directory

Preciso alterar a senha de um usuario do AD utilizando php e powershell
seria assim: conectar ao AD com o ldap, escrever linha de codigo powershell no php e executa-la, fazendo que ela execute no AD tambem, escrevi uma linha para mostrar os parametros de um usuario mas nao funciona!

```
if (ldap_bind($ldap_con, $ldap_dn, $ldap_pass))
{
    echo Shell_Exec('Get-ADUser -Identity Usuario -Properties mail');

}
```

chequei o apache error.log e aparece isso:

O termo 'Get-ADUser' nÆo ‚ reconhecido como nome de cmdlet, fun‡Æo, arquivo de script ou programa 
oper vel. Verifique a grafia do nome ou, se um caminho tiver sido inclu¡do, veja se o caminho esta  correto e tente 
novamente.

Comment: tenta `echo Shell_Exec('powershell Get-ADUser -Identity Usuario -Properties mail');`

Comment: Não aparece nada

Answer (score 0):

Tente invocando o **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** usando:

```ps
 -NoProfile -Command "seus comandos"  ==  -nop -c  "seus comandos"
```

- Ou ainda.

```ps
 -Ex -Command "seus comandos" == -ex -c  "seus comandos"
```

- Onde seu **[php](/questions/tagged/php)** com **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** ficaria:

```ps
if (ldap_bind($ldap_con, $ldap_dn, $ldap_pass))
{
    echo Shell_Exec('powershell.exe -nop -c "Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity Usuario_AD -NewPassword $senha_nova -Reset"')
}
```

- Ou ainda.

```ps
if (ldap_bind($ldap_con, $ldap_dn, $ldap_pass))
{
    echo Shell_Exec('powershell.exe -nop -c "Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity Usuario_AD -OldPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "senha_antiga" -Force) -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "senha_nova" -Force')
}
```

Opcionalmente, se for deixar para o próprio usuário fazê-lo, é só agendar para o próximo login:

```ps
if (ldap_bind($ldap_con, $ldap_dn, $ldap_pass))
{
    echo Shell_Exec('powershell.exe -nop -c "Set-ADUser -Identity Usuario_AD -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true"')
}
```

Consulte mais detalhes:

**[Set-ADAccountPassword](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-adaccountpassword?view=win10-ps)**

**[Run a Powershell script from PHP](https://www.itdroplets.com/run-a-powershell-script-from-php)**

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou forçar a importação do módulo antes da execução do Get-ADUser?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```